# Assemble a 9 * 9 * 0.05 mm steel foil and castellation PCB using standard pick and place

Tags: surface-mount, pcb-assembly, solder-paste

I have a hybrid PCB where I want to assemble a very thin steel foil on a PCB using standard pick and place SMT process. the picture below describe how the foil is like:
[image]

[image]

The orange area is only hold by fine traces and therefore can swing, and we want it to swing using a passive placed on a second castellation PCB assembled on top (passive in red).
Is it a standard practice (at least 50% of PCBA facilities can do without problem) to pick and place the castellation PCB while making the orange area move down?

If yes, do you think it,s possible to do standard, or we should use some kind of smt adhesive to hold the castellation PCB and avoid it being pushed up by the orange membrane?

Comment: what is a `passive` ?

Comment: what does this mean? `assemble steel standard`

Comment: Why do you care whether >50% of manufacturers are able to do it? Wouldn't it be more relevant either whether *your* manufacturer can do it, or where you can find one that can?

Comment: @jsotola: a passive means a capacitor, resistor, simple pin, anything simple not powered, "assemble steel standard" means no special process or extra cost is involved with soldering steel on HASL or ENIG pads using solder paste

Comment: @immibis it's important because that way I know it won't be very expensive and if things go wrong for a reason or another with my manufacturer I still can find another fast enough and not struggle to rebuild the entire process from scratch

Comment: Independently on the pads(HASL, ENIG), steel won't be solderable with standard paste.

Comment: @WesleyLee this is why we intend to Tin plate the rectangular areas

Comment: the plate is going to be picked up by a single P&P head (using suction) - depending on a lot of things (like it's real size and actual weight) it most likely needs to be picked up at it's center of mass (the size of the P&P picker head depends on how heavy it is) - my guess is that it's going to be by the orange area - the answer may depend on whether that's OK

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but it sounds like you plan to place this on top of other components. It seems like that might not work very well. Might cause the covered component to move prior to reflow, and also, it may shield the component so that the solder does not fully reflow in the oven.

Comment: Could you not form the piece prior to assembly?

Comment: @Taniwha, thanks for your feedback. Indeed I guess the center of mass would probably be on the orange area, this means the pads could not be pressed to touch the PCB. is there a way we can pick using a smaller sucking tool and pick from outside the orange area.

Comment: Can we do it using two passes of assembly: 1 pass -> assemble all standard SMT components and reflow, 2 nd pass -> assemble and reflow only the foil with lower reflow temperature profile. Is this easily achievable ?

Comment: @TarikMokafih, I know two-pass reflow is sometimes done, but I don't know a lot about it. I know pick-and-place USUALLY uses one nozzle near the center of mass, but I don't know if it is possible to use multiple nozzles for odd shaped pieces. That is why I was thinking that you could form your metal piece  (bend it over a form) so that it doesn't have to be pushed down when it is installed. It will be pre-bent into the right shape so that it rests on the six solder points, and the center will be raised so that it won't impinge on the covered capacitor.

Comment: @mkeith the orange area is a flexible membrane which can move up and down, so itcan not just be bent before assembly

Comment: Ah. I thought the whole thing was steel.

Comment: I think there can be a few problems with this. 1. Soldering it level with the board. I don't know how tall will be this passive element, but it might be troublesome to place the steel part so it sticks to the solder paste and does not lift. 2. Will you be able to get these steel parts in some packaging that PnP machine can use? (like reel or tray) If not, assembler will have to find some packaging for it or place it by hand (additional cost).

Comment: Regarding the main question - I think that PnP machine wouldn't have much problem with picking this kind of part on the side and detecting it. In my opinion, it would be problematic to press it down on to the PCB so it stays uniformly flat at both sides. But it depends on the height of component, flexibility of the orange part, flexibility of the steel part and probably few more things. Either way - I don't think it can qualify as "standard assembly". Maybe it would be best to leave it for hand assembly? (depends on quantity of PCBs)

Comment: Since I gave up on the first idea, I now think about using a constellation PCB is that easier to achieve ?

Comment: Don't use comment threads as a discussion forum. Either you have a specific question _about this exact question_, or you can answer the question separately, or you can ask a new question.